# How to asynchronously process parts of unordered_map?

Tags: c++, multithreading, for-loop, asynchronous, unordered-map

For each pair from unordered_map<string, string> I need to call the processing function. It does not return anything and does not change the data in any way. How, using std::async or std::thread should I asynchronously process map parts?

I was trying to do something like this

```
unordered_map<string, string> m = Init();
vector<std::thread> threads;

for (size_t i = std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); i > 0; --i) {
    // for loop ???
    threads.emplace_back(do_smth, it); // Here it is iterator of element in m
  
}

while (!threads.empty()) {
     if (threads.back().joinable()) {
        threads.back().join();
     }
     threads.pop_back();
}
```

But what should be instead // for loop ??? ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't state, which c++ standard you use for your project. But if you have at least c++17 at your disposal, the problem is solved very easily by employing the std library (but without std::async or std::thread, if that's not a hard requirement for you):

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>

void exec(std::pair<std::string,std::string> p) { // your processing function
    std::cout << "executing " << p.first << " : " << p.second << "\n";
}

int main () {
    std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> m=
    {{"a","A"},{"b","B"},{"c","C"},{"d","D"},};

std::for_each(std::execution::par,m.cbegin(),m.cend(),exec);
}
```

You can see this solution live in action [here](https://godbolt.org/z/oxzo8jr49) .

Answer (score 1):

As a first cut at it, I'd create:

- a concurrent queue
- a pool of threads

The main thread will push items to the queue. The other threads will do something like this:

```cpp
while (queue.pop(item))
    process(item);
```

After you've pushed all the real items to the queue, you can (for one possibility) push N (= number of threads) dummy items. Attempting to pop a dummy item returns `false`.